# Saving a Model in OPENAI Baselines

Tags: model, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, baseline

Openai Baselines save the trained model with the following command,

```
python -m baselines.run --alg=ppo2 --env=PongNoFrameskip-v4 --num_timesteps=2e7 --save_path=~/models/pong_20M_ppo2
```

But the saved trained model is not in the form of,

```
.ckpt.meta
.ckpt.index
.ckpt.data
checkpoint
```

which it was in this form in the earlier versions. How can we save the model as .ckpt.meta, .ckpt.index, .ckpt.data and checkpoint format?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem and I've solved the problem by making a little adjustment to the baselines code.

There are two pairs of methods in baselines for saving and  loading models(the save_state&load_state pair and the save_variables&loas_variables pair) and you can see it in *baselines/common/tf_util.py*(line325~line372).

For the latest version of baselines, the save_state&load_state  pair which saves and loads models in the .ckpt.meta, .ckpt.index, .ckpt.data and checkpoint format has been abandoned, so you need to re-enable the save_state&load_state pair.

Take ppo2 for example, in *baselines/ppo2/model.py*, make the following replacement:
in line 125, replace

```
self.save = functools.partial(save_variables, sess=sess)
self.load = functools.partial(load_variables, sess=sess)
```

with

```
self.save = functools.partial(save_state, sess=sess)
self.load = functools.partial(load_state, sess=sess)
```

and in line 4,
replace

```
from baselines.common.tf_util import get_session, save_variables, load_variables
```

with

```
from baselines.common.tf_util import get_session, save_state, load_state
```

this will replace the save_variables&loas_variables pair with the save_state&load_state pair.

hope this would help you.